# Sharepoint foundation: how to make the new site collection look like the exisiting one?

Tags: sharepoint

totally sharepoint newbie here, was asked to create a sharepoint collection which mimic the exisiting look and feel for another website, how can i archieve this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

With a SharePoint foundation it is quite difficult to do cause you are limited in options. The server version is customizable from A to Z: master pages, page layouts etc...

When you work with SP foundation the only option is to work with themes which are built in SharePoint and which can be customize. You can create your own theme. See  [here](http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1138) to for more information about how to customize SP site.

I can advise you to see [these](http://www.sharepointpackages.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=77) examples...

Hope it helps,

Andrew